# Why is my vuetify dialog hidden behind this evil overlay?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a vuetiful component which should just display a dialog. Unfortunately, an evil overlay has taken over the domverse. How do I overcome the forces of semi-transparent darkness?

```
Vue.component('step-form', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            dialog: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showDialog() {
            this.dialog=!this.dialog;
        }
    },
    template: `
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
        Help, I'm hidden behind this evil "overlay"!
    </v-dialog>
`
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJpWGx

Comment: You've probably noticed this already, but wrapping the content of the dialog in a `v-card` component seems to put the overlay behind the dialog. I have no idea why though.

Comment: as @DelenaMalan mentioned wrapping dialog content with v-card will put overlay behind  `<v-dialog  
 v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
              <v-card>
Help, I'm hidden behind this evil "overlay"!</v-card>
    </v-dialog>`

Comment: Thanks guys - at best an undocumented workaround - at worst an evil bug?

Comment: @DelenaMalan `v-card` doesn't put dialog behind overlay, it already is behind it. It just looks like it isn't due to shadows and being transparent and persistent. It's not a bug. See my answer. Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[It's not](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBJWya).

You simply don't have background color inside v-dialog. You can put `v-card` inside for example.
You just used `persistent` property which makes you unable to close it on-overlay-click, and have no other means to close it.
So dialog has `z-index: 202`, and overlay has `201` apparently, so dialog is  above overlay,
but `box-shadow` makes it look like like it's floating behind it or something, but it's because it's transparent, and you just need to set background-color.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I initially had a `<v-card-title>` element inside the dialog - I was missing the `<v-card>` element and everything was a grayer shade of pale.

Comment: good idea and working great thank u traxo for your great solution

Answer (score 7):

use `hide-overlay`

change to below code

```
<v-dialog hide-overlay
 v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
        Help, I'm hidden behind this evil "overlay"!
    </v-dialog>
```

Documentation : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs

Comment: Okaaay... this seems to be a workaround. Surely the overlay should be *behind* the dialog.

Comment: Incorrect, because it seems that op wants preserve the overlay, and not hide it.

Comment: Incorrect, I *am* the OP and I just want to see my dialog.